# How to use dynamic variables with Ansible pull?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

With ansible-pull, everything runs on the client and the tasks are running as `localhost`. I tried setting a dummy inventory file with a variable as seen below. Depending on the hostname, I want the variables set accordingly. I think my issue is, the FQDN isn't being used correctly.

## inventoryfile

```
[web_servers]
myweb001.phl.domain.local
myweb004.phl.domain.local
myweb005.phl.domain.local

[perl_servers]
myperl011.phl.domain.local
myperl001.phl.domain.local
myperl010.phl.domain.local

[web_servers:vars]
server_type=web
some_random_variable=20

[perl_servers:vars]
server_type=perl
some_random_variable=40
```

## task

```
- hosts: localhost

tasks:
  - debug: var={{ server_type }}
```

## output

```
PLAY [localhost]    ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'server_type' is undefined"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
to retry, use: --limit @test.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your playbook with `hosts: localhost`, you may try following:

**inventory**

```
localhost ansible_connection=local

[web_servers]
[web_servers:vars]
server_type=web

[perl_servers]
[perl_servers:vars]
server_type=perl
```

**playbook**

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - group_by: key=web_servers
      when: "'myweb' in ansible_hostname"
    - group_by: key=perl_servers
      when: "'myperl' in ansible_hostname"
    - debug: var=server_type
```

Instead of `group_by` and inventory file, you may want to use `include_vars` to dynamically load specific variable files, based on ansible_hostname or some other criteria.